# how to make list view smooth?

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

I'm creating an app which has an image and text inside a listview and I am loading the data from json http. My list view is smooth in emulator but when installed it on my phone, its a bit lag and I think my problem is on my model because it gets lag everytime I scroll to the next item. perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

my model XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="Fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/batulao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70.0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/mtimg" />
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="#f4ff79"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mtnametxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="4.5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/masltxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="3.5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="3.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/difficultytxt" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```